# Issues with two elements side by side

Tags: html, css

This has got me stumped. Trying various code options.

On my test site, I have two elements that I wish to show next to each other.

I have tried some stripped down code, but still the two are beneath each other. The heights are important as one side contains 2 items from a database and the other 5 and so to make the two boxes the same length, I need to include the heights.

```
<div style="height: 340px; width:100%; white-space:nowrap;">
<div style="width: 49%;  width: calc(50% - 8px);   width: -moz-calc(50% - 8px);  width: -webkit-calc(50% - 8px); height: 340px; ">
    <!-- START ARTICLE POSITION 1 -->
    <div style="height: 170px;">text</div>
    <!-- START ARTICLE POSITION 2 -->
    <div style="height: 150px;">
        <div style="padding-top: 10px;">text</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style=" background: #eee; width: 49%;  width: calc(50% - 8px);   width: -moz-calc(50% - 8px);  width: -webkit-calc(50% - 8px); ">
    <!-- START ARTICLE POSITION 1 -->
    <div style=" height: 48px; overflow: hidden;">text</div>
    <!-- START ARTICLE POSITION 2 -->
    <div style=" height: 48px; padding-top: 20px; overflow: hidden;">text</div>
    <div style=" height: 48px; padding-top: 20px; overflow: hidden;">text</div>
    <div style="height: 48px; padding-top: 20px; overflow: hidden;">text</div>
    <div style=" height: 48px; padding-top: 20px; overflow: hidden;">text</div>
</div>
```

Can anyone let me know where I have gone wrong.  I appreciate that everything is inline currently, but not sure that should affect things.

Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.

Whilst I can see that they work here, when I make the 'live' it fails miserably, and puts them one beneath the other. Am going to leave them both at 47% which is what I have currently. It looks a bit odd in wider screens, but perfect at 1024.  

Thanks anyway for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `float:left` the divs and give each one **50% of width**:

```
<div style="height: 340px; width:100%; white-space:nowrap;">
<div style="width: 49%;  width:50%;   height: 340px; float:left;background:#ddd">
    <!-- START ARTICLE POSITION 1 -->
    <div style="height: 170px;">text</div>
    <!-- START ARTICLE POSITION 2 -->
    <div style="height: 150px;">
        <div style="padding-top: 10px;">text</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style=" background: #000; width: 49%;  width: 50%; float:left  ">
    <!-- START ARTICLE POSITION 1 -->
    <div style=" height: 48px; overflow: hidden;">text</div>
    <!-- START ARTICLE POSITION 2 -->
    <div style=" height: 48px; padding-top: 20px; overflow: hidden;">text</div>
    <div style=" height: 48px; padding-top: 20px; overflow: hidden;">text</div>
    <div style="height: 48px; padding-top: 20px; overflow: hidden;">text</div>
    <div style=" height: 48px; padding-top: 20px; overflow: hidden;">text</div>
</div>
```

### [Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ignaciocorreia/8pgFR/)

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS `float:left`

Here goes the **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SxxWV/33/)**

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
 <div style="height: 340px; width:100%; white-space:nowrap;">
            <div style="width: 49%;  width: calc(50% - 8px);   width: -moz-calc(50% - 8px);  width: -webkit-calc(50% - 8px); height: 340px; ">
                <!-- START ARTICLE POSITION 1 -->
                <div style="height: 170px;">text</div>
                <!-- START ARTICLE POSITION 2 -->
                <div style="height: 150px;">
                    <div style="padding-top: 10px;">text</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style=" background: #eee; width: 49%;  width: calc(50% - 8px);   width: -moz-calc(50% - 8px);  width: -webkit-calc(50% - 8px); position:absoulout  left: calc(50%);position: absolute;top: 0;">
                <!-- START ARTICLE POSITION 1 -->
                <div style=" height: 48px; overflow: hidden;">text</div>
                <!-- START ARTICLE POSITION 2 -->
                <div style=" height: 48px; padding-top: 20px; overflow: hidden;">text</div>
                <div style=" height: 48px; padding-top: 20px; overflow: hidden;">text</div>
                <div style="height: 48px; padding-top: 20px; overflow: hidden;">text</div>
                <div style=" height: 48px; padding-top: 20px; overflow: hidden;">text</div>
            </div>
```